# How to check if tuple key contains an element in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am looking for an operation that could do something similar to this:

```
dict[ ( tuple[0] , _ ) ]
```

The dictionary contains tuples as keys.

How do I check if the dictionary contains a value where the tuple key has a specific value as the first part and any value as the second part?

Comment: To use a dictionary efficiently, the key should be the exact thing you want to use to look stuff up. So in this case the key should be the first part of your tuple. Otherwise you're left with iterating through all the keys to check each one, which loses the benefit of a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide an example, the question is not clear.

Comment: Could you provide a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @khelwood what do you mean by first part of my tuple? Does that mean converting the dictionary keys into single values?

Comment: You said you want to look for a key that has a "specific value as the first part". That first part should be what you're using as the key. If you want to look stuff up in your dictionary without knowing the second part of the key, that second part should not have been included in the key at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#Dictionary with tuples as keys
dict_with_tup = dict([((1,2),3), ((1,4),2), ((2,5),7)])

#value that you wanna find (just the first value of the tuple)
x = 1

#filtered dict based on that value
{k:v for k,v in dict_with_tup.items() if k[0]==x}
```

```
{(1, 2): 3, (1, 4): 2}
```

Comment: Not really, you need to search and search means iterations. The best you can do is use a list comprehension as i have done, which is superfast.

Answer (score 0):

for a dictionary d

```
x = # value of interest
for key in d.keys():
    if key[0] == x:
        #do stuff
```

but as [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) noted in the comments, it's not a very efficient way of doing things